# Tikz triangle formatting

Tags: tikz-styles

I have a problem when i am drawing triangles in TikZ. 
If i want to add a value to the figure then it looks odd and are laying in layers.

is there any way to "beautify" this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[above] {$a=1.4$} (B) -- node[right] {$c=0,8$} (C) -- node[below] {$b1,1$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can for example add the `sloped` option to the `node` above the hypotenuse. Note also that by default a thin space is added after a comma in math mode. One way to avoid that is to use the `\num` macro of `siunitx` to print numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

Compare:\par$1,1$\par\num{1,1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[sloped,above] {$a=\num{1.4}$} (B) -- node[right] {$c=\num{0,8}$} (C) -- node[below] {$b=\num{1,1}$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```